# INSERT takes over 5 hours, when inserting more than specific number of rows

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query-performance

When inserting less then about 1,350,000 rows to the table it all takes about 2 minutes, however when number of inserted rows is bigger, then the time needed to insert data grows to about 5 hours.

The problem is not connected with query or indexes, because everything has been working fine for a long time and nothing has changed in the structure of query, tables or indexes.

Problem appeared for the first time about 2 weeks ago and it appears repeatedly on days, when number of inserted rows is bigger than +-1,350,000. For example on one day number of inserted rows is 1,200,000 and the process takes 2 minutes, on the other day number of rows is 1,450,000 and it takes 5-6 hours to insert data.

I tried to rebuild indexes, but it has not helped.

Comment: What is the source for the insert?

Comment: Can you post what is the [wait associated](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) when insert is taking such a long time ?

Comment: We can only guess unless you give more information. My guess is lock escalation happening. Can you track down waits and lock escalation

Comment: Is this the first time you are trying to insert 1.3 million records? Are you doing transactions? Bulk Import? What type of logging are you doing? If you are doing plain-jane inserts, I agree, try doing the inserts in batches.

Comment: It might be a long shot, but maybe it would help to wrap like every 10-30k inserts into a `TRANSACTION`? I've had good experience with this practice and greatly shortened my insert times.

Comment: Do the logs say anything ?

Comment: How do you import the data (bcp, bulk insert, SSIS, batch file)? Where from (local storage, same/different drive, network storage, ..)? What's the table schema? What's the import command? What's the execution plan (if it's plain T-SQL)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess would be - if you are not actually being blocked - that you are hitting a threshold above which the data file (and/or log file) has to grow, and that your configuration is not optimized to support this growth. Ensure that:

1. Your data file growth rate is reasonable, and is a fixed size (not %!) large enough to accommodate this transaction and anything else that may be going on concurrently.
2. Same for log file.
3. [Instant file initialization is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization). This will help speed up data file growths but not the often more troublesome log file growths.
4. You aren't inserting 1.35 million individual rows in a loop or otherwise all as one big transaction. There is something to be said for [breaking your transactions into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Comment: Aaron is spot on with his suggestions sounds like filegrowth on data or logfiles. Also make sure you virtual log file count is low.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be a memory issue?

You could see this sort of behavior if some chunk of data that must be repeatedly accessed grows too big for memory and you get disk thrash from hell.  If you have to loop across a chunk of data that's too big for memory you end up with the whole thing being read back in from the swap file for every pass, pushing it over that limit can cause your performance to fall off a cliff.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to / is it possible to divide them into smaller batches? When I've encountered a similar issue, grouping them by 5.000 (with GO) has really lowered the time it took to complete such a task.